# Join selected features from different shapefiles (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have two different shapefiles, with selected points.
I want to create a new shapefile with only the selected features of those two shapefiles.

Comment: Run the `Extract selected features` tool from the Processing Toolbox for both layers. Then run the `Merge vector layers` tool and select both outputs from the first tool for merging. You could also create a model to automate this task.